# Dynamically change chart after clicking an icon in Excel

Tags: excel, charts, dashboard

I am doing a dashboard. To resolve the problem with the space, I would like to show a chart which changes depending of which icon an user clicks (see image in following link: http://screencast.com/t/IvzllhxCi).

Charts are already done and ranges defined. The chart showed in the dashboard was inserted using the "Paste picture link" function (sorry if this is not the correct name, but I use Excel in spanish).  I assume, that the best way to do it is creating different macros which define the data of a chart and are fired which every icon click, but... is there a more efficient way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about just creating all the charts, putting them on top of each other and then showing / hidding the appropriate chart when a user clicks the icons via:

```
chart.Visible = xlSheetHidden;
```

And

```
chart.Visible = xlSheetVisible;
```

Comment: it works really smooth and it is a really easy solution because I do not have to define ranges, titles, axis formats... Thx for discovering me the chart.visible ;)